# jQuery Cycle2 carousel pager issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2, cycle2

I have successfully setup a carousel linked pager slider show, along the lines of the demo.  However the functionality is little bit imperfect and I need a solution.

The code is  using just the directives

```
<div id="slideshow-1">
<div id="cycle-1" class="cycle-slideshow"
    data-cycle-prev="#slideshow-1 .cycle-prev"
    data-cycle-next="#slideshow-1 .cycle-next"
    data-cycle-swipe=true
    data-cycle-swipe-fx=scrollHorz
    data-cycle-timeout="0"
    data-cycle-auto-height="800:500"
    >
...
<div id="cycle-2" class="cycle-slideshow"
    data-cycle-slides="> div"
    data-cycle-timeout="0"
    data-cycle-prev="#slideshow-2 .cycle-prev"
    data-cycle-next="#slideshow-2 .cycle-next"
    data-cycle-fx="carousel"
    data-cycle-carousel-visible="5"
    data-cycle-carousel-fluid="true"
    data-allow-wrap="false"
    >
...
```

The issue is as follows, when you reach the end of the carousel using 'next', the carousel stops but only on the first of the 5 displayed. Which is counter intuitive, as you would expect clicking next would 4 more time would take you to the last of the carousel.

One option is to data-allow-wrap="true",  as the wrap means that it continues as you click next, but setting this removes the ability to click on any of the 5 display carousel images  - is this a bug? Is there a work around?

Another option would be to remove the 'next' indicator on hitting the end (5th from end ) and leave it to the user to work out they have to click on the remaining 4 carousel images.  This is less than ideal, but how can you identify this state and remove the 'next' (presumably with abut of jQuery?)

Comment: The second part of my question/solution can be done will css. Not the best UX but does the job.  
    #slideshow-2 .cycle-next.disabled { display:none;}

Comment: and it seems the wrap true issue is potentially a bug https://github.com/malsup/cycle2/issues/224